# função inspectdb equivalente no node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarn

Olá! Em Django existe uma função chamdado [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/) que mapeia todo banco de dados criando modelos do arquivo model.py.

Existe alguma função ou lib equivalente javascript ou node.js?

Answer (score 0):

No Node.JS existe um ORM chamado **Sequelize**, o mesmo possui um comando chamado **sequelize-auto**, com ele conseguimos criar os models a partir de um banco de dados existente como no Django utilizando o inspectdb.

O Sequelize tem suporte a vários bancos de dados, veja na documentação as dependências necessárias para o seu banco de dados.

Segue abaixo a documentação: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelizeauto